# Pause and resume a running script in Python 3.42 in Windows

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and have been googling for a couple of days and read all I can find on this forum. Might be that I don't understand it all but I haven't found a solution to my problem yet. Ask for forgiveness already if there's an answer already to my problem, then I haven't understood it.

I want to make a Pause function for my program Tennismatch. The program will when it's being run print the score of a tennis match like this: "15-0, 15-15 etc ongoing till the match ends. It will print the score line by line.

I want the user to be able to pause after x number of balls, games, etc. So I don't know when the user wants to pause and after the user has paused I want the user to be able to resume the tennismatch where it was.

Have seen the time.sleep() but as I have understood it you must know when you want to pause to use this and it also ain't an indefinetie pause like I want. With input() it's the same.

Am going to make a GUI later on when the code is finished. Happy for anything that leads me to solving my problem.

I use Windows and Python 3.42 and run the program in Shell.

A piece of the code (haven't written it all yet, it's more of a general situation when something is being printed line after line for some time and want to be able do pause in the CIL:

```html
#self.__points = [0,0]
def playGame(self):
    if self.server == True:       #self.server is either True or False when someone calls playGame()
        server = self.player_1.get_win_serve()   #self.player_1 = an object of a class Player():
    else:
        server = self.player_2.get_win_serve()   #get_win_serve() method returns the probability to win his serv (1-0)
    while (0 < self.__points[0] - self.__points[1] >= 2 or 0 < self.__points[1] - self.__points[0] >= 2) and (self.__points[1] >= 4 or self.__points[0] >= 4): 
        x = random.uniform(0,1)    
        if x > 0 and x < server:
            self.__points[0] += 1
            
        else:
            self.__points[1] += 1

            # print('The score, by calling a score() function that I haven't written yet')
```

Comment: You should show us your code, preferably a cut-down version that illustrates your problem, so we can clearly understand what you're talking about. FWIW, implementing a pause / delay in a CLI program generally uses a slightly different strategy to what's required in a GUI program. But I guess it can be easier to do a GUI version if you understand how to do a CLI version.

Comment: This is non-trivial. You basically need to loop continuously, reading keystrokes from the user in a *non-blocking* manner, and switch an internal "pause" state in your program if, and only if, a keystroke has been read. Getting a single keystroke in a non-blocking way, without using multithreading, is very platform specific though.

Comment: Have added some code that I have so far.

Comment: you should start with more fundamental things such as how do you accept input (keyboard/mouse) from a user while running your game. Once you know that; it is trivial to add pause()/resume() methods. For example, look at how `pygame` framework does it.

Comment: How do I implement accept input in Shell which is a CLI? My plan was to use tkinter as GUI later on. I understand that's its easier done in GUI, but my task is to make it in both a GUI and the CLI.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian but that's exactly the crux here ("accept input *while* running your game"), and the main point of the OPs question (even if he might not realize that). And the problem is, both approaches (multi-threading or non-blocking IO) are anything but fundamental - that's a big leap from a simple CLI.

Comment: @LukasGraf: `while True: for event in pygame.event.get(): # process events` is not a rocket science. My point: there is no point to discuss how to implement pause/unpause unless we know what is the specific event loop is used (it might be implied). If OP doesn't know it then OP should ask a different question (or start with any tutorial that creates any game that accepts input from a user while performing some action concurrently). Either way pause/unpause is red herring.

Comment: The Event loop might as well be the code I wrote with. Print('15-0') in the end. It will not matter. Then if you have any suggestions or tips on tutorials of that kind I would love to get some. I just want to learn more. I currently read a course in which we use the litterature "Python for the absolute beginner". As the making of a pause function was a comment in my tasks description I thought that it couldn't be such a difficult thing to do in the CIL. Since it came as a requirement before making a GUI. But tips on how to proceed from here to develop is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following.

```
 while True:
        try:
            ## Keep doing something here
            ## your regular code
            print '.',

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            ## write or call pause function which could be time.sleep()
            print '\nPausing...  (Hit ENTER to continue, type quit to exit.)'
            try:
                response = raw_input()
                if response.lower() == 'quit':
                    break
                print 'Quitting...'
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print 'Resuming...'
                continue
```

Comment: @Tennisfan Actually time.sleeps() does not connect with keyboard interrupt or like you said "press". It simply halts the execution of program for few seconds.

Comment: @d-coder -1 because `time.sleep()` is absolutely unsuited for the OP's purpose. He wants to implement a pause / unpause mechanism initiated and terminated by keystrokes, not "pause for a given duration that's known in advance".

Comment: I know that input works like that. But then I have to have a code after pause and code before pause exactly as whit time.sleep(), which I don't have since I don't know when the user wants to pause.

Comment: Removed my `-1` because this actually kind of works. There's some serious drawbacks though: You're limited to binding the "pause" action to `KeyboardInterrupt` (`CTRL+C`), you couldn't possibly bind it to the `p` key with this method for example. Because of that, you also eliminate the possibility of ever using `CTRL+C` to terminate the program, as usual.

Comment: You can write what should keep happening until there is an keyboard interrupt. If user press something while execution of program then it'll halt giving that message. Next if user presses `quit` then write the code for quitting your script else write the code that should happen after resuming

Comment: Then I have to insert my code in the try statement. But I want to implement a pause function(). Also we still have the problem that I don't know the code that should come after the interruption. I want  it to resume where it was.

Comment: You can call one function which pauses the script in the first except statement

Answer (score 0):

For dealing with events in main loop you need to make a separated thread which capture input or any other event.

```
import sys
from sys import stdin
from time import sleep
from threading  import Thread
from Queue import Queue, Empty


def do_something():
    sleep(1)
    print 42


def enqueue_output(queue):
    while True:
        # reading line from stdin and pushing to shared queue
        input = stdin.readline()
        print "got input ", input
        queue.put(input)


queue = Queue()
t = Thread(target=enqueue_output, args=(queue,))
t.daemon = True
t.start()

pause = False

try:
    while True:
        try:
            command = queue.get_nowait().strip()
            print 'got from queue ', command
        except Empty:
            print "queue is empty"
            command = None

        if command:
            if command == 'p':
                pause = True

            if command == 'u':
                pause = False

        if not pause:
            print pause
            do_something()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

> The Event loop might as well be the code I wrote with.

I don't see any user input so I assume that `x` emulates it. To pause the game if `x < 0.1` and to unpause(/resume) it if `x > 0.9`, you could:

```
while your_condition(self.__points): 
    x = random.random()
    if x < 0.1: # pause
       self.pause()
    elif x > 0.9: # resume
       self.resume()
    if self.is_paused:
       continue # do nothing else only wait for input (`x`)
                # assume your_condition() has no side-effects

    # here's what the resumed version does:
    print("...")
    # change self.__points, etc
```

where `pause()`, `resume()`, `is_paused()` methods could be implemented as:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.is_paused = False
def pause(self):
    self.is_paused = True
def resume(self):
    self.is_paused = False
```

as you can see the implementation is very simple.

Comment: This I understand and could be useful in other tasks as the one you mentionet when setting conditions depending on x in this case. But it should keep printing the score, independetly of the value of x. But thanks for the display of implementing pausefucntion when you have easier conditions deciding whether to pause or not. So the continue just returns to the beginning of the loop correct?

Comment: @Tennisfan: yes, `continue` skippes the rest of the loop. *"It should print independetly of the value of x"* - what does "pause" mean in your case? I've assumed it means that no printing, no recalculating of score should occur while the game is paused. Note: `x` is just a place-holder for user input. In a real program, you should use some event instead of `x` such as: a user pressed `'p'` key on the keyboard.

Comment: Well you are correct about how the pause should work. Some missconception from my side though since I use a variable x in my code that doesn't effect the eventual pause condition.